# Switch network for all wallets reactjs Blocknative

Tags: metamask, wallets, react

Is there a common way to switch networks for all wallets that can be connected to my dapp in reactjs. I'm using Blocknative and ethers. Or do I have to implement a network switch for each wallet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various ways to do that

1. (Recommended) You can use wagmi.sh to do that. They also have built-in networking switching and it's by far the best library I've used - https://wagmi.sh/docs/hooks/useNetwork
2. You can use web3-react which has built-in switch network - https://github.com/NoahZinsmeister/web3-react/tree/v6/docs#unsupportedchainiderror
3. You can use vanilla JS to do it but it requires you to use event listeners to listen for metamask's events. https://docs.metamask.io/guide/rpc-api.html#unrestricted-methods